# How does an internet server respond to a request from a private IP?

Tags: router, routing, tcpip

I'm learning about private/public IPs, port forwarding and NAT, and still fail to see the answer to a simple question:

Suppose two users on the same network are communicating with a single server outside their network (say, me & my wife send http requests to yahoo.com).  The server sees both users as a single public ip, and often - as in this case - communicating on the same port.  How does the router route the packets according to the two different connections? Is there any routing info inside the packet beyond ip/port?  Is there some 'session table' maintained somewhere? By whom and what exactly does it include?

Comment: There is a [NAT table](http://www.firewall.cx/networking-topics/network-address-translation-nat/228-nat-table.html) in the router

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Within a computer, between processes

First let's see how a *single* computer distinguishes between concurrent connections.

Most transport protocols such as TCP, UDP, SCTP **use *two* ports, source and destination** – i.e. one on either end of the connection. That is, packets *do not* simply walk "through" a port; instead they travel *from* port X *to* port Y.

The *destination* port is usually well-known (80 for HTTP, 53 for DNS…) but the *source* port is usually randomly chosen by the OS itself, which also ensures that the src/dst combination is unique.

So when your browser makes multiple connections "to Yahoo's port 80", all of them actually have different *source ports*, and the OS keeps a socket table such as:

```
PROCESS       PROTO  LOCAL                REMOTE            STATE
9894/firefox  tcp    192.168.6.175:39163  google.server:80  established
9894/firefox  tcp    192.168.6.175:52909  yahoo.server:80   established
17463/chrome  tcp    192.168.6.175:64981  yahoo.server:80   established
9894/firefox  udp    192.168.6.175:4984   8.8.8.8:53        --
```

So when the OS receives a TCP packet from `yahoo.server:80` to local port 52909, it can map it to the specific connection made by Firefox.

Important to note that this has nothing to do with NAT *yet*, and happens the same way even if you're directly connected. (NAT will make use of it, though.)

(You can see this table using `netstat -n`, or various graphical tools on Windows. Often "local/remote" are labelled "source/destination", although that's not entirely accurate.)

---

#### Within a NATed network, between computers

The answer to your question about NAT is very similar, only everything is done at a larger scale.

The router performing NAT keeps a "state" table containing both the internal and external addresses & ports. For example, if your two HTTP requests used separate TCP connections, they might be tracked as:

```
PROTO   ORIG-SRC             ORIG-DST         REPLY-SRC        REPLY-DST
6/tcp   192.168.6.42:52909   yahoo.server:80  yahoo.server:80  your.public.ip.addr:52909
6/tcp   192.168.6.175:39163  yahoo.server:80  yahoo.server:80  your.public.ip.addr:39163
6/tcp   192.168.6.175:52909  yahoo.server:80  yahoo.server:80  your.public.ip.addr:28330
17/udp  192.168.6.175:4984   8.8.8.8:53       8.8.8.8:53       your.public.ip.addr:4984
```

When the router receives a packet from REPLY-SRC (Yahoo) addressed to REPLY-DST (your public IP address), it knows that the *real* destination must be taken from the ORIG-SRC column in order to undo the NAT.

*(If there's no matching state, then manually configured port-forwarding rules are processed. If still none match, then the packet was really meant for the router itself.)*

Note how the state table contains **addresses *and* ports**, allowing multiple connections to the same server to be distinguished by the port combination. In my example, two computers accidentally used the same port combination, so the 2nd connection had its ports translated as well.

(In fact, some NATs look *only* at the port and ignore the source address completely; this reduces the number of possible connections, but makes it a lot easier for peer-to-peer programs to perform "NAT hole-punching".)

Such state is kept even for connectionless protocols such as UDP or ICMP, so the entries expire after some interval of inactivity even though there's no explicit "close connection" packet. (The state table is actually part of the firewall, so even if NAT isn't done, the router might still use it to distinguish between "active" connections and stray packets.)

(If your router is Linux-based, `conntrack -L` or `cat /proc/net/nf_conntrack` would show this table. For OpenBSD or pfSense, try `pfctl -s state`.)

Comment: Thank you. Are 52909 and 39163 in your example ports or something else? If these are ports used for http, how come they're not 80? How are clashes avoided?  (Or: what happens when both ports are 40000?)

Comment: @OfekShilon: They're example ports. Note that TCP and UDP uses _two_ ports – source and destination. That's how a single computer distinguishes between multiple connections to the same Yahoo server. The _destination_ port is "well-known" (80 for HTTP), but the source port is usually chosen randomly by the OS, which ensures that the src+dest combination is unique. Finally, if two computers try to use the same port combination, your NAT router will just rewrite the conflicting ports too. (It's often more accurately called NAPT.)