# How does the router open ports on outgoing requests?

Tags: networking, router, ip, port, nat

When Alice connects to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), the router forwards that request to the internet and listens for a response from [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) on a port.

- Is this port unique? (*I.e. will the router ever expect responses from multiple websites to this port*)
- Is the port closed directly after the response has come through?
- Is it possible for Alice to know **which** port was opened by the router?

Alice now opens the website in more tabs, making more requests.

- Is each request assigned a new port by the router?
- If so, is there a limit to the amount of outgoing request? (As the amount of possible ports is finite)

Comment: Since this is likely homework, the correct answers to earn your points are in the course book and related materials. The answers to these questions are much more nuanced in reality than the yes/no described by the questions asked (as you can probably tell from User1686's answer).

Comment: It's not a homework, but an attempt to understand a related problem my friend ran into that none of us could find the solution to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this port unique? (I.e. will the router ever expect responses from multiple websites to this port)

It might be, but it doesn't have to be. (It varies.) The router knows packet addresses *and* ports – so there's nothing fundamentally preventing it from tracking multiple connections with the same local port but different remote servers. I think some implementations *try* to avoid re-using the same port, though.

> Is the port closed directly after the response has come through?

The router doesn't really know about "requests" and "responses". Those are application concepts defined by HTTP, but the router only cares about TCP connections (i.e. immediately above IP layer), and TCP is a free-form data stream that doesn't distinguish what's a request and what's a response.

That's is important to keep in mind when asking about websites, because most browsers send multiple HTTP requests over the same TCP connection and only close it after it has been idle for a while. (This [HTTP connection reuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) wasn't part of HTTP *originally*, but was added as an optional feature in ~1995.)

So to answer the question, the port is closed when the browser decides to close the TCP connection and the router sees the corresponding "shutdown" packets go through.

> Is it possible for Alice to know which port was opened by the router?

Not directly – only by asking an external server which port it sees packets coming from. (Games and P2P software do this through the STUN protocol).

If a fixed port number is necessary, usually one adds a *static* port mapping rule to the router (aka "port forwarding") instead of relying on the dynamic ones.

> Is each request assigned a new port by the router?

As mentioned above, HTTP requests do not correspond 1:1 to TCP connections. The "port number" is set for the entire TCP connection, and the browser is able to send multiple HTTP requests over the same connection.

Whether each TCP connection is assigned a new port... it varies.

At this point, remember that the router doesn't actually *create* ports. TCP connections have always used port numbers for identification – before NAT existed, before private LAN addresses existed. Your own computer's OS chooses the local port number, and the router's NAT merely translates ports the same way it translates IP addresses.

(See also [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1253022/how-does-an-internet-server-respond-to-a-request-from-a-private-ip/1253026#1253026).)

So with that in mind:

- Your computer usually assigns a new port number for every new connection. It deliberately tries to avoid using the same port number for a short period of time (the "TIME_WAIT" state). Some operating systems use an incrementing port number, others choose it randomly.
- When the connection reaches your router, some routers use a type of NAT that tries to preserve the original source port number (chosen by your computer) as far as possible, and only reassign it in case of duplicates with another device.
- But some other routers use a type of NAT that *always* reassigns the port number to something completely random, for each new connection. (These are often called "Symmetric NAT.")

> If so, is there a limit to the amount of outgoing request? (As the amount of possible ports is finite)

Yes, although the theoretical limit doesn't always match the practical limit.

As mentioned above, the router or the computer can – in theory – reuse the same local port as long as other parameters (remote IP and/or remote port) are different. But in practice, most operating systems don't do this and reserve the port number in its entirety, leading to a limit of just 64k connections. The same goes for routers, too, when they try to cram all LAN connections under your single public IP address.

Also, not all local ports are available for use as source ports. Generally, the range 1–1023 is nearly always off-limits (due to being the primary range for *destination* ports), and the range 1024–49151 is sometimes avoided for the same reason.

Finally, an issue with home routers is that they sometimes have such miserable amounts of RAM that they cannot keep track of so many connections in memory – when overwhelmed, they'll either start refusing new ones or kicking off old ones.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and qualitative response!
I have a question regarding if it would be possible for two computers, A and B, to communicate directly over internet even with an active firewall.

If A opens a TCP connection to B (thereby whitelisting Bs IP-address on the port that was opened by the router) and B found this port (either though port iteration or using STUN), could a stable connection then be made between the two?

Comment: Often, yes, that's more or less what STUN is for. (Search for "NAT hole punching.") However, in some NAT types (especially "Symmetric NAT"), the port seen by the STUN server will _not_ be usable from other IP addresses and the trick won't work.

Comment: Very interesting and thanks again! If anyone is looking for a solution the same problem as I am, there is more information about it on [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal) and [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hole_punching_(networking))