# How packets are delivered from server to local network?

Tags: networking, router, nat

I am new to networking and am trying to understand how packets are routed on the way back from the server. I learned that when packets go out from the local network, the source address is translated into a public address. But I can't understand how the address translated from public to private. So I assume some rules on NAT router on ISP's side are applied. It would be helpful if somebody explain the process in detail.

Comment: Couldn't find a good duplicate, but this is probably answered by the 2nd half of https://superuser.com/a/1253026.

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? Do you have any progress to share? [how the address translated from public to private](https://superuser.com/search?q=+how+the+address+translated+from+public+to+private) returns 63 results. Are there any of these relevant?

Comment: Searching `how the address translated from public to private` in Google returned the following as featured snipped `Network Address Translation (NAT) is a protocol that translates public IP addresses to private IP addresses and private addresses back to public. You'll often see NAT enabled on an Internet-facing firewall.` The source of this snippet is https://blogs.getcertifiedgetahead.com/translating-public-and-private-ip-addresses/. Does this source is relavant to this question?