# How routers deal with only one external IP?

Tags: linux, networking, router, iptables, nat

I recently discovered that all my devices connected to a WiFi router have the same external IP. Call it `20.20.20.20`. The thing that I don't understand is how the router figures out which IP packet coming from `WAN` should be forwarded to which device on `WLAN`.

Precisely I have the following topology:

```
   PC (192.168.1.149) --
                        |
                        |-----> (192.168.1.1) WiFi router (20.20.20.20) ----> WAN
                        |
Phone (192.168.1.139) --
```

My first thought that router forwards all traffic coming from `WAN` to all the devices, but capturing `tcpdump` on a `PC` did not show the traffic for the phone. From googling I understand that all routers do is performing NAT, but the question is how `iptables -t nat` would look like in the case?

Percisely, how the `TCP` connection from both `PC` and `Phone` to the same external IP e.g. `30.30.30.30` and port `22222` is handled.

Also if I send a random IP packet to the IP `20.20.20.20` which device it will be forwarded to?

Comment: `how iptables -t nat would look like in the case` The iptables `nat` table does not record the mapping of the original socket and the NAT'd socket (in which a different, random port number will be used if necessary). Netfilter/Conntrack does. To enable SNAT you just need to have a `-j SNAT` or `-j MASQUERADE` rule for the traffics it matched (e.g. `-s 192.168.1.0/24`). With the mapping keep tracked of, reversed DNAT can / will be applied when the destination host replies, which is how the replies can eventually goes to the original source host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a very basic explanation.

Your devices uses private addresses. Private addresses are subnets/networks with the following IP addresses (see [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918)):

- 10.0.0.0 to 10.255.255.255
- 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255
- 192.168.0.0 to 192.168.255.255

Private addresses are not routed over the internet (in theory, they can be routed by ISPs block them). They (private addresses) are translated via NAT (Network Address Translation) or PAT (Port Address Translation) using your public address.

To the external world, packets coming out of your router have the same address. Your router when receiving packets that must be routed to external network adds a port number (in the case of PAT) to differentiate the device that sent it. It randomizes the port number and prevents th same port to be used by two devices on its routing table. Thus, although the same public addess is used, the port number will be different.

Answer (score 3):

> From googling I understand that all routers do is performing NAT

NAT is still an "add-on" feature *on top* of actual routing. When a reply comes in, after NAT it still follows the regular routing process.

> but the question is how iptables -t nat would look like in the case?

It's just one rule – most of the work is done by a separate "conntrack" subsystem.

For outbound connections, the router only needs a single `SNAT` or `MASQUERADE` rule:

```
-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o <wan_interface> -j MASQUERADE
```

(The two actions are identical except for 'MASQUERADE' automatically choosing what IP address to use – it'll use whatever address the WAN interface has, while 'SNAT' requires one to be specified within the rule.)

The whole `-t nat` table is special in that packets only go through it when they aren't matched by any conntrack state. You can use **`conntrack -L`** to see a list of active states.

The first packet of a connection hits the iptables rule and establishes the state, everything else is done by conntrack – when a reply comes in, the inverse translation is done by conntrack.

(Conntrack is used both by the filter rules **and** NAT rules – e.g. the common `-m state --state established` filter rule also relies on the same conntrack, even if no NAT is done – so don't be surprised if you see a ton of states even on a non-router system, or on a router that's not configured for NAT.)

"Port forwarding" is similar; it's a `DNAT` rule.

```
-t nat -A PREROUTING -i <wan_interface> -d <wan_ip> -p tcp --dport <wan_port>
                                           -j DNAT --dnat-to <lan_ip:port>
```

> Percisely, how the TCP connection from both PC and Phone to the same external IP e.g. 30.30.30.30 and port 22222 is handled.

The two connections come from different *source* ports. It's the same situation as when your web browser makes two identical connections to the same server – even if the destination port is equal, the source port is chosen randomly in order to result in a unique `(src, dst, proto, sport, dport)` combination.

With NAT, in case both devices happen to choose the same source port, the router will translate the source port in order to retain uniqueness.

(I have a better example at [How does an internet server respond to a request from a private IP?](https://superuser.com/questions/1253022/how-does-an-internet-server-respond-to-a-request-from-a-private-ip/1253026#1253026))

When looking at the conntrack table, note how the "orig" and "reply" fields include not just the IP address but the port as well. If an inbound packet arrives to REPLY-IP:REPLY-PORT, it is NATed to ORIG-IP:ORIG-PORT, allowing the "local" port (source port from the PC's perspective) to be made unique if needed.

> Also if I send a random IP packet to the IP 20.20.20.20 which device it will be forwarded to?

None, unless an iptables rule explicitly NATs it to something.

The WAN IP address doesn't belong to your LAN as a whole – it belongs specifically to the router as a device, so by default such packets are handled as if you're **connecting to the router itself**.

Answer (score 0):

They keep track of the ports at each live device level.

The external ip is on the network of the wan, so connections to it are going to be handled by the router over a specific local and remote port on the TCP/IP or "Transport Layer".

Otherwise yes there would be no way of doing NAT.

To doublecheck said answer did a search.

[Nat Answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/217087/how-does-nat-keep-track-of-connections)

Looks like someone agrees. And truthfully its the only thing that makes sense.

So on the network behind your router and with your other local network hardware layer 2 is visible, which contains the hardware or mac address of the pieces of "live" equipment involved in a network conversation.

These addresses do not make it past the local subnet which usually is terminated logically when traffic reaches a router.

The ip addresses are assigned by the local device or the dhcp server and enforced.

In the good old chaotic days this could result in whats called an IP collision when two layer two addresses had the same layer 3 address.

Now this is all for the convenience of the local network, as obviously the external IP address is leased by an ISP in the case of internet connections through hardware that interfaces with their network.

Your computers and devices want to access internet addresses, but will all share the ip address on the wan facing port of the router, so what information is commonly included when forging a tcp/ip socket connection, or a opening a software port to listen for incoming connections ?

The software port of a listening server starts out the same, as it advertises its service via this port.

The side note confronting our cultures departure from reality once again.

The way networks are designed if you even change subnet mask, you need a router to pass network traffic from one to the other because the address range does not match. This was also meant to more efficiently control traffic instead of just acting like a hub and repeating the packet out of every port until another device answered.

Anyway, so I forge a connection to [www.google.com:80](http://www.google.com:80).

My ip address is 192.168.1.2.

The router, a layer 3 device, sees this and says... 'well hell, what to do.. what to do...'. It checks its routing table for either configured default route or for a specific IP range, and the router says "the destination IP address is this, if i have a configured ip range associated with a specific hardware port, use this route, otherwise use the default route", then it translates the addresses to the next network the hardware port's IP is set to.

So what it does do is it updates a data structure listing connections that are supposed to be ongoing between local ips and ips elsewhere, and has a table that says "which port reaches this ip address".

so it says "ok, hey google (sorry pardon the play on words), hey google, I wanna connect to you on port 80" now the external ip address is what google sees.

so google says "Ok well i need to clear this port to accept other connections, so heres the first available port 62433" (or maybe its random who cares).  Meanwhile your local device has already decided what its local port is, which we'll say is 5020, and the router has said "ok i'm connecting on your behalf, talk to me on port 6120", but the router is speaking to google on 62433, and google is speaking to it on port 5111.

so you have the a data structure which will likely keep track of the age of connection for timeout purposes, and say:

192.168.1.2,  5020, 6120, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), 5111,62433,

now the transaction can continue.

google via several network hops which replicate this, relays its response from port 62433 (which may be the port provided by another router) to your external ip address on port 5111, the router looks this up and says "OH ITS THIS ITEM, AND ITS GOING TOOOOOOOO" 192.168.1.2 ON PORT 5020 FROM PORT 6120, WHICH IS ON THIS PHYSICAL PORT (Or its wifi, sorry so there are no ports just the wlan device), and it updates the headers of the transport layer, and then drops a frame on the local network, after making a bunch of noise and waiting for an acknowledgement that the packet was received.

make sense ?

PS note sure what format it stores the date of last activity in, but this would be necessary otherwise you'd have numerous ports being eaten up by connections that were being made and your hardware would have no more software ports in the case of dropped connections or timeouts.

I'm pretty sure that the origin ip of the host on the wan is always kept the same when the reply is sent back, so all the magic happening in between replicates this process at every major hardware jump.

You can see this to some extent, though some of it is obfuscated by using the traceroute utility, which will show you the hops.

You can also view the packeted activity by using a packet sniffer like wireshark.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer has the right idea but has quite a few wrong  statements. Its also quite wordy for what it communicates and has a lot of irrelevant bits.

Comment: @davidgo point out what is wrong please. I would like to know.

Comment: Its to much for a comment.  Here are some - tracking tracking  does not take place at "each live device level". Not all NAT traffic can use ports (eg ICMP). You have dest ip field to work with and ignored protocol specific elements that can be used. You incorrectly and irrelevantly assert IP address allocation is enforced and needs to be through DHCP. DHCP has nithing to do with NAT. Not all routable IPs are leased and you ignore Carrier Grade NAT,  There is no forgery going on - its the header being rewritten,  The " hey google" bit implying dns lookup/chenanigans is misleading...

Comment: as NAT does not tie in to DNS. Your talk about hops is irrelevant and misleading, NAT does not know or care of [switch]  phsical ports - thats handled by ARP,  NAT does not make noise on the LAN, it relies on timeouts and tracking tables and only manipulates packets passing through it - ie it dies not generate nak packets, There is no replicating anything at each hardware jump. NAT does not obfusicate traceroute. A packet sniffer will only make nat obvious if it is run on the router (not   usually an option) or you run it on 2 devices - one on each side if the connection.

Comment: did i not read that post correctly ? Point is read my answer.  dns is performed by the client. the ip address is what is placed in the packet yes i get that.

Comment: however the 'hey google' cheninagans is tying in whats happening on the socket level to the answer which is relevant

Comment: we're talking an ordinary tcp/ip connection in the example. for clarity.