Do router NAT rules for one computer affect traffic for another?
I have a router that accesses internet, and 2 computers C1, and C2 behind it.
C1 runs a  (higher importance) service that needs a few fixed inbound ports, so there are NAT rules to forward those ports to it.
C2 runs another (less important) service that needs a range of inbound ports being open, so inbound traffic on those ports of the router is forwarded to it. Say 40000:50000 for example
Now, C1 is not aware of the inbound ports that will be forwarded to C2. It could make a request to some remote service, and say 'respond me on port 45000'.
What would happen after the router? Is the response port kept? In which case C1 could not receive all those answers anymore since they would be sent to C2?
Or does the router adjust it's asked inbound port to receive the response, so there is never any conflict with any port forwarding rule, and will then forward that to the response port asked by C1?
Or should i tell somehow to the Linux system config of C1 that it should not use the inbound range of C2 in the dynamically chosen response ports?

Does this answer your question? Portforwarding to multiple computers

It varies between routers, but fundamentally, the port can remain without conflicts in most cases. The router does however choose a different port if it needs to, but in your example that wouldn't be necessary.
The NAT in your router is stateful; it keeps a table of "active connections" (aka states or flows) together with their NAT configuration. For every incoming packet, it checks the state table to determine the internal IP address associated with that specific flow before it checks the general NAT rules; therefore an inbound "port forwarding" rule on UDP port 40000 only takes effect if the packet didn't match any known flow (i.e. is a 'new' packet).
(Most home routers literally use Linux iptables and conntrack under the hood, and the same table is used both for the NAT and for the stateful firewall.)
So as long as other parameters are distinct, there shouldn't be conflicts; although not guaranteed that all routers behave the same way – in particular, "cone NAT" vs "symmetric NAT" (not to be confused with 1:1 NAT...) will behave differently, I believe.
However, as a different example, if two internal hosts both make outbound connections with the same parameters (same src port, same dst port, same dst addr, and the router SNATs them to the same src addr), then the router will also SNAT one of them to a different src port to preserve the uniqueness.
I have an older answer with examples: https://superuser.com/a/1253026/1686

It depends on a few things.
If the program uses uPNP, the router will automatically create internal rules and tags traffic so it reaches the right server once traffic is flowing.
Another option is that the program establishes an inbound connection, but the serverside, then creates new connections the other way. Outbound traffic does not require NATrules on your side, but requires uPNP to be active on the other side. This is almost always the case.
It is also possible that that a program specificies that you must open a port range, and that it uses the port range. If this were the case, you would've known though.
It is also possible that the program expects uPNP to be active and will simply fail if it isn't.
